# Which version of GLSL supports Indexing in Fragment Shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a fragment shader that iterates over some input data and on old hardwares I get:

> error C6013: Only arrays of texcoords may be indexed in this profile, and only with a loop index variable

Googling around I saw a lot of things like "hardware prior to XX doesnt support indexing on fragment shader".

I was wondering if this behavior is standardized in GLSL versions, something like "glsl version pior to XX doesnt support indexing on fragment shader". And if so, which version starts supporting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular error comes from the Nvidia compiler for nv4x (GeForce 6/7 cards), and is a limitation of the hardware.  Any workaround would require disabling the hardware completely and using pure software rendering.

All versions of GLSL support indexing in the language -- this error falls under the catch-all of exceeding the hardware resource limits.

Comment: Do you have any sugestion on how to detect if my hardware is capable of indexing in fragment shader?

Comment: Try to compile the shader and check if there's an error.  If there is, the hardware doesn't support it...

Answer (score 2):

What is your exact hardware ?

Old ATI cards (below X1600) and their drivers have such issues. Most certainly, not the most recent cards from Intel also suffer from this.

> > "Do you have any sugestion on how to detect if my hardware is capable of indexing in fragment shader?"

The only reliable yet not-so-beautiful way is to get the Renderer information:

```
glGetString(GL_RENDERER)
```

and check if this renderer occurs in the list of unsupported ones.